# how can i return the boot loader of the windows 7 and windows xp and linux

Tags: windows, linux, bootloader

today i wanted to find the way to create a bootable program and make my flash bootable and test it . i search many sites to do that.
first i go to [this](http://linuxgazette.net/issue77/krishnakumar.html) site . but this site explain the way to write program to make bootable the FLOPPY and when i see the command`./write`i cant do this command with my flash.
then after googling this:`hello world boot sector` (that i see from another site) i found [this](http://viralpatel.net/taj/tutorial/hello_world_bootloader.php) site. although this site is explain to make FLOPPY bootable disk. i see this command:

```
dd if=boot.bin bs=512 of=/dev/fd0
```

i knew that `fd0` is device that mounted the floppy disk drive.
i think that i can replace `fd0` with `sdb` or`sdc` or other,but i dont know exactly what name refers to the flash that i connect to computer , so i type above command 6 times for every `sdb` and `sdc` and `sda` and `sda2` and `sda4` and ....
then certainly the file copied to flash and make it bootable.
so i was happy to do that and restart the computer and set the first boot device to flash then i see that its work but when i remove flash and return the previous option of bios priority boot device(to hdd) i see that bootloader of winodws dont load.:(

Answer (score 0):

There are several .iso images that you can download and put on an USB drive or CD/DVD to boot from that will let you reinstall, for example, GRUB in the boot sector of the hard drive that you set to first boot device.

That way you might be able to restore to ability to boot into different operating systems on your machine.

But, and this is a big but, when you used dd to write your new boot sector to all those devices and partitions, you most certainly destroyed the partition information or in some other way damaged the information stored on your hard drives.

Never, ever, use dd blindly to "get something somewhere" since you are writing raw disc sectors and even if you manage to restore your multi-boot capability, Window and Linux might very well refuse to start.

Comment: can you say some .iso files that i can download them?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and safest would be to make a bootable CD (using rewritable media is best) or USB. Here's [how to do it with CDs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7776577/968261).

Comment: okay,then what must i do then ?creating a bootable flash to doing what ?